# How to show Only a selected Number of Database entries on the page

Tags: php, html, mysql

The question is, if I have got 100 entries in my Database and want them all getting displayed on my page, how can I only show a selected Number like it's the case in webshops etc.
    There you've got 37 products e.g. and after 10 products you have to select number 2 of the entry list.Its all split up in a few sites, but its still the same site.How can i achieve this.

Comment: It's called pagination and [Google is your friend..](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20pagination%20examples)

Comment: Pagination as noted above and ajax, https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: thx, yes im sorry, but english is not my native english and i wasnt able to find something, cause i didnt know how to search for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the pagination either by client side implementations or server side. 
Client side (using Java Script/JQuery) and Server Side (using PHP) is preferable.

For client side, just follow this 
[link](https://www.datatables.net/)

For Server side

[PHP Pagination](http://code.runnable.com/U8dzQWEzMxxqeQ_E/php-pagination-example-using-mysql-database-for-dbms)

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you put php, html and mysql as tags on your question so it's mean you don't have a clue on what you are doing. You should really study those things in separate a little more.

For the MySQL part you must study the [limit directive](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx).

The html part is not big deal also, you will have to make a pagination system. As said before Google is your friend.

On the server-side (php) you should look for the parameters/url on the page defined by the html part and make the proper query.

If I would enter in details of each of those steps I would have to write several paragraphs and still would be things missing. Well, at least I've given you directions, now you really should study more before attempting to do things like this.

Next time don't ask questions too vague/broad. Try to focus on specific issues rather than asking for the whole solution.

Comment: I know, what im doing, i just found it useless to put my code Here since its a general question and. Not code specific.I know PHP, MySQL and HTML and how to use them, i just didnt know about pragination...

Comment: OK, then you should have narrowed your question to the issue. If you have a code that is incomplete or not working you always should post so everyone can see where is your problem, suggest modifications, improvements and of course know where exactly you have been reached a wall. Sorry if I have offended you in any way.

Comment: You didnt :-) ill keep that in mind